# Regex to match exactly n occurrences of letters and m occurrences of digits

Tags: java, regex

I have to match an 8 character string, which can contain exactly 2 letters (1 uppercase and 1 lowercase), and exactly 6 digits, but they can be permutated arbitrarily.

So, basically:

- K82v6686 would pass
- 3w28E020 would pass
- 1276eQ900 would fail (too long)
- 98Y78k9k would fail (three letters)
- A09B2197 would fail (two capital letters)

I've tried using the positive lookahead to make sure that the string contains digits, uppercase and lowercase letters, but I have trouble with limiting it to a certain number of occurrences. I suppose I could go about it by including all possible combinations of where the letters and digits can occur:

```
(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]) ([A-Z][a-z][0-9]{6})|([A-Z][0-9][a-z][0-9]{5})| ... | ([0-9]{6}[a-z][A-Z])
```

But that's a very roundabout way of doing it, and I'm wondering if there's a better solution.

Comment: Which engine are you using? Is it possible to split the regex into multiple tests? i.e. apart from letters does it contain exactly two letters and then if it contains exactly six digits?

Comment: I'm using Java 8. The letters and digits can be anywhere. It's only important that there is exactly 6 digits, exactly 1 uppercase letter and exactly 1 lowercase letter. It doesn't matter where in the string they are located.

Comment: I'd probably write a short method to check this (without regex). That will be much easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: I recommend you this training tool: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z][^A-Z]*$)(?=[^a-z]*[a-z][^a-z]*$)(?=(?:\D*\d){6}\D*$)[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hC4tC8/3) (a bit modified due to the multiline input). In Java, do not forget to use double backslashes (e.g. `\\d` to match a digit).

Here is a breakdown:

- `^` - start of string (assuming no multiline flag is to be used)
- `(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z][^A-Z]*$)` - check if there is only 1 uppercase letter (use `\p{Lu}` to match any Unicode uppercase letter and `\P{Lu}` to match any character other than that)
- `(?=[^a-z]*[a-z][^a-z]*$)` - similar check if there is only 1 lowercase letter (alternatively, use `\p{Ll}` and `\P{Ll}` to match Unicode letters)
- `(?=(?:\D*\d){6}\D*$)` - check if there are six digits in a string (=from the beginning of the string, there can be 0 or more non-digit symbols (`\D` matches any character but a digit, you may also replace it with `[^0-9]`), then followed by a digit (`\d`) and then followed by 0 or more non-digit characters (`\D*`) up to the end of string (`$`)) and then
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}` - match exactly 8 alphanumeric characters.
- `$` - end of string.

Following the logic, we can even reduce this to just

```
^(?=[^a-z]*[a-z][^a-z]*$)(?=(?:\D*\d){6}\D*$)[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}$
```

One condition can be removed as we only allow lower- and uppercase letters and digits with `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, and when we apply 2 conditions the 3rd one is automatically performed when *matching* the string (one character must be an uppercase in this case).

When using it with Java `matches()` method, there is no need to use `^` and `$` anchors at the start and end of the pattern, but you still need it in the lookaheads:

```
String s = "K82v6686";
String rx = "(?=[^a-z]*[a-z][^a-z]*$)" +      // 1 lowercase letter check
            "(?=(?:\\D*\\d){6}\\D*$)" +       // 6 digits check
            "[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}";                 // matching 8 alphanum chars exactly
if (s.matches(rx)) {
    System.out.println("Valid"); 
}
```

Comment: I thin we can reduce it even to a much shorter variant.

Comment: Can you explain, how does the (?=(?:\D*\d){6}\D*$) check for 6 digits? In particular, what does the \D* inside the non-capturing group do?

Comment: I added explanation to that part of regex. Actually, all the look-ahead conditions are based on reverse character classes: you match 0 or more characters other than SOMETHING and then you match only one occurrence of SOMETHING, a specified number of times (with a limiting quantifier `{n,m}`) and then match any number of occurrences of characters other than SOMETHING up to the end of string.

Comment: Thank you, that was a very helpful answer :)

Comment: Just drop `(?=(?:\D*\d){6}\D*$)` from your first solution and fine.

Comment: @bobblebubble: Actually, removing any one condition keeping only two is fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
Pattern.matches(".*[A-Z].*", s) &&
Pattern.matches(".*[a-z].*", s) &&
Pattern.matches(".*(\\D*\\d){6}.*", s) &&
Pattern.matches(".{8}", s)
```

As we need an *alternating automaton* to be created for this task, it's much simpler to use a conjunction of regexps for constituent types of character.

We require it to have at least one lowercase letter, one uppercase letter and 6 digits, which three classes are mutually exclusive. And with the last condition we require the length of string to be exactly the sum of these numbers in such a way leaving no room for extra characters beyond the desired types. Of course we may say `s.lenght() == 8` as the last condition term but this would break the style :).

Answer (score 1):

Sort the string lexically and then match against `^(?:[a-z][A-Z]|[A-Z][a-z])[0-9]{6}$`.